# AWS RDB - why did master and slave databases get swapped?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

A few weeks ago, I spun up an RDS Aurora A-Z instance. It automatically created two instances: the main one and a read-only replica.

Last week I used the mysql command line interface to login to the main mysql instance and I successfully created a new table. Today, I used the mysql command line interface to login to the main mysql instance, tried to make a change, and got an error that said that the database was read-only. I then looked in the AWS RDB console, and it appears that the main and the replica have switched. The main is read-only and the replica is the writer.

I noticed that about 2 hours ago, and the situation has not changed. So this is not happening because of a maintenance window (since the maintenance windows are only 30 minutes long).

Why would this have happened? Is there something I should do to prevent this from happening in the future?

Comment: This is MySQL, not Aurora, correct?  If MySQL, I'm afraid there is no documented mechanism by which this could be explained, nor any mechanism of which I can conceive.  Not even maintenance windows would explain this -- RDS simply doesn't do that -- transposing the replication roles of two MySQL servers is a logistically complex and somewhat delicate operation, certainly not possible to do by accident, nor is it possible to even do this deliberately via the console.  The only conceivable mechanism is that the machines didn't change, but their instance names (thus hostnames) were transposed.

Comment: I sincerely don't want to insult your intelligence by suggesting you're simply remembering it wrong and nothing in RDS has actually changed... but absent some historical documentation to prove otherwise, I am otherwise lost.  The results of `SELECT @@SERVER_ID, @@HOSTNAME` from each instance before and after, for example, would tend to help prove or disprove.  The graph of Replica Lag is the only thing coming to mind now -- if the current replica has a history of data there and the master does not, it suggests the instances are unchanged, but proves little about the instance names.

Comment: Are you *certain* you're not talking about a multi-AZ RDS?

Comment: It shouldn't be that, @ceejayoz.  The backup/spare instance in MySQL multi-AZ isn't user-accessible.  It just runs hidden in the background until a failover event... pretty much a black box, it can't be used as a read replica.

Comment: Also, the "Created Time" values in the console for each instance should tell a story -- it isn't possible for a replica to have been created before its master, in RDS for MySQL.  This is on the "Details" tab (paper with magnifying glass icon) when you click on an instance.

Comment: Sorry, my original post said MySQL, but it actually is Aurora multi-A-Z.  Both instances show the same "Created Time" (4 weeks ago).  However, the logs for instance that is currently writeable go back 4 weeks, but the logs for the instance that is currently read-only only go back 5 days.  Also, these instance have had very little usage (and very little data), since they are for an app that is not live yet.

Comment: Yeah, that's quite a bit different. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They may have switched due to maintenance.  There's a [pending upgrade to Aurora 1.7.1 dated 2016-09-20](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Aurora.DatabaseEngineUpdates.20160920.html) showing for one of my Aurora clusters now (on 2016-10-15, `SELECT @@AURORA_VERSION;` shows 1.6).  It would make sense if the replicas were upgraded first, then a failover event was triggered, and then the master would be upgraded, but I'm speculating -- I can't find this explictly stated in the documentation.

Or, there could have been a failure of the original master, that resulted in a failover followed by recovery of the original master.

Either way, you should find evidence of *something* in the instance event logs, assuming it was recent -- see "Events" on the left hand side of the RDS console.

But as to why they switched and then didn't switch back is a question that's potentially easier to answer -- I don't believe there's a reason to expect them to switch back.

At any point in time, one of your instances is the "master" -- but unlike MySQL/MariaDB native replication, calling it the "master" isn't really accurate, because the instances in an Aurora cluster all share a common backing store -- they don't have individual copies of the data, they're all peers accessing a shared and replicated storage back-end.  Rather than master and slaves/replicas, one of them is a **writer** (can read and write) and the others (if they exist, a single instance "cluster" is valid) are **readers** (read only), but any one of the instances can become the writer due to a failover event (which may be triggered for reasons other than an actual failure).  It's possible to prioritize the instances so that failover causes a switch to a preferred instance (the instances in an Aurora cluster don't have to be the same instance class) but this only seems relevant when the number of nodes is greater than two.

Fundamentally, though, the design of Aurora appears to be such that you shouldn't be thinking of your instances as though a specific one of them is the master... and the infrastructure provides a way for it not to matter.

An Aurora cluster has a cluster name assigned by you and an alphanumeric cluster identifier assigned by the system, and each instance in the cluster has a name assigned by you.

Aurora, as is standard behavior for RDS, creates a hostname in DNS for each instance based on the name you give to the instance and the cluster identifier, but an Aurora cluster has two additional hostnames created -- one that will connect you to the writer, and another that will connect you to one of the readers (or, it will also connect you to the sole member of the cluster, which is in fact the writer, when the cluster has only one member).

So let's say your cluster name is `prod-db`, let's say your system-assigned identifier is `xyzzyexample`, and let's say the nodes you created are named `node-1` and `node-2`... and the region is `us-east-1`.

The instance hostnames look like this:

```
node-1.xyzzyexample.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com # instance 1
node-2.xyzzyexample.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com # instance 2
```

But the hostnames you should be using to access Aurora are not those.

The ones you should be using, unless you have a specific reason to do otherwise, such as pinning a job to a specific replica, look like this:

```
prod-db.cluster-xyzzyexample.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com    # writer
prod-db.cluster-ro-xyzzyexample.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com # reader
```

These are implemented as CNAMEs in DNS, managed by RDS, so each time you connect, you get an answer appropriate to the current configuration of your cluster.  The TTLs are 5 seconds on the writer address, and 1 second on the reader address, so the odds are pretty good that the answer will be correct.  By using these addresses to connect, you don't have to be concerned with the machines switching roles.

Comment: Thanks!  My problem was that I was using the instance domain name instead of the cluster domain name.